# How can I display charts with a asp.net control on web page?

Tags: asp.net, statistics, reporting

I want to display chart on my web page for which I have the the source (for X & Y axis values) table in sqlserver.

Answer (score 3):

Use the official Microsoft [Charting Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Comment: this is a really easy and powerful way of displaying charts - works great.

Answer (score 0):

So many ways ...

If it's just X and Y you can really use some sort of 'div' structure.

If you want more complicated than that, just go with a .net charting application (trivial to find via searching).

Answer (score 0):

[Google charts](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/chart/) is a convenient way to display charts on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to display chart in asp.net using asp.net chart control